# Error using wrapfigure

Tags: errors, wrapfigure

I am trying to use wrapfigure but I cannot get it to work each time I get the error `Latex Error: Environment wrapfigure undefined`. I have included `\usepackage{wrapfig}` in my document and the script I'm writing is:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{1.5in}
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{dna.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the information you're giving, you seem to be using ``wrapfigure`` properly, so it's hard to tell what's the problem. Could you make your example complete, that is starting with ``\documentclass{...}`` and ending with ``\end{document}``, while still reproducing the problem?

Comment: Are you using `\usepackage{wrapfig}` in your preamble? That's the package that defines that environment.

Comment: yes I have it in my preamble but it's still not working. I can't reproduce the entire document as it is part of a large report. Hence all I can do is report the issue I am having with it @Vincent